# custom UITableViewCell works on simulator but not on device

Tags: ios, uitableview, xib

on the simulator the view with custom table view loads fine .. but on device its throwing this error

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle  (loaded)' with name 'MyCustomCELL'' ***

the xib is in 'Target membership' in 'show file inspector' 
also exists in 'build phases' 'copy bundle resources'

my test device is ipod touch 3rd gen ..

any help is appreciated :)

Comment: are the simulator and ipod on the same iOS version?

Comment: yes .. actually it was working fine on the device, before I added the custom tableViewCell ..

Comment: does the custom cell have extremely large images or do anything out of the ordinary?

Comment: that is helpful info - I would suggest systematically removing the text then the image to see what is causing it to not load on the device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

often a file not found error is a mismatch in the case of the filename
osx HFS is case-insensitive
ios is case-sensitive

Comment: great .. now its working fine ... instead of "MyCustomCell" I have put "MyCustomCELL".. thanks..

Comment: bit me often enough in the past ^^ since then, all my resources are lower-case :D